# php ternary if / else with sizeof always false?

Tags: php, ternary

I've got a strange, (but hopefully simple miss) issue with ternary assignment in PHP.  Below $category is set to blank which means sizeof($data) is evaluating to 0.  My expectation is that it should be assigned 'Test Category'.

```
$data=array('Test Category');
$category= (sizeof($data)>0 ? trim($data[0]) : '');
```

If I instead do the following, I get $category with a value 'Test Category', why doesn't the ternary operator work as below?

```
if(sizeof($data)>0){
  $category=trim($data[0]);
}
```

Comment: `$data` is an array?

Comment: Seems to work as expected: https://eval.in/842312

Comment: Use if($data) {} OR  if(!empty($data))

Comment: `$category= (sizeof($data)>0 ? trim($data[0]) : '');` worked for me, Whats not working for you?

Comment: ternary statements evaluate both true and false arguments regardless of the conditional statement so if `$data` doesn't exist you're going to run into problems. Use `if` statements instead for this kind of thing

Comment: $data does exist, its checked against not existing before this code.  Ternary assignment is supposed to be an if/else composite, so I'd not expect if(){} to operate differently.  I noted in the question that a normal if produces the expected result, my question is why not the ternary.

Comment: Just asking to make sure, is this exactly your code? I mean isn't there the slightest difference between what you wrote here and the actual code? Because this works as expected.

Comment: i just copied your code an pasted to my editor , it's work as acpected

Comment: Grr.  line above the code was messing it up!!!!!  This works as expected. More coffee.

Answer (score 2):

How about checking `$data[0]` like this:

```
if(isset($data[0]) && !empty($data[0])){
    $category=trim($data[0]);
}
```

You can change this to ternary as follows:

```
$category = (isset($data[0]) && !empty($data[0])) ? $data[0] : '';
```

Comment: It is better answer.

Comment: This ternary works, but the question remains why is isset($data[0]) && !empty($data[0] different than sizeof($data)>0. And why different than than count($data)>0 where $data is an array of size 1.  @Nawan's answer seems to indicate that if the array value in $data[0]=='' that this has something to do with it evaluating false?

Comment: Here is a demo to help you understand. Just try creating an empty array, and you will see that `count` and `sizeof` would give result as 1 but the condition mentioned in my code won't result to `true`. Here is demo: https://3v4l.org/AJTlF

Answer (score 0):

You failed writing your ternary assignement, look at your parenthesis.

Try: `$category= (sizeof($data)>0) ? trim($data[0]) : '';`

Answer (score 0):

if your array have an empty value means you get the same result like this here is two example for the code:

```
$data=array();

$category= (sizeof($data)>0 ? trim($data[0]) : 'no');
echo $category; // output is no
```

another one is:

```
$data=array('');

$category= (sizeof($data)>0 ? trim($data[0]) : 'no');
echo $category; //output is empty. it wont show the 'no'
```

In your case check if test category is empty value or null Your code:

```
$data=array('Test Category');

$category= (sizeof($data)>0 ? trim($data[0]) : 'no');
echo $category; //output is Test Category
```